# React-Native black screen when reboot after a crash in production

Tags: react-redux, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-router-flux

I have a problem with my react-native app that appear both **android** and **iOS** but only in **release** configuration.

When the app crash for any reason, it will stuck at boot at the next start even if I kill it on device.

It's hard to debug, cause it's in release mod only.

Do someone have a similar issue ? or an idea of how to find the problem ?

I'm with 
react: 16.0.0-alpha.6 
react-native: 0.44.0 
react-redux: 4.4.6 
react-native-router-flux: 3.38.0

Thank you!